# Basic Parallax - Background jerking up

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I have a simple code for moving the background images, but the image is jerking up once the section is in view. the idea is for the background-pos to move only when the section is in view.

Any ideas?

```
$window = $(window);
$('.portfolioSection').each(function(){
  var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object
  var speed = 8;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + 150 >= $bgobj.offset().top){
      // Scroll the background at var speed
      // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                                
      var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / speed);

      // Put together our final background position
      var coords = '0 '+ yPos + 'px'

      // Move the background
      $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    }
  }); // window scroll Ends

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it- I didn't account for the section position - Line 9

```
var yPos = -(($window.scrollTop()-$bgobj.offset().top) / speed);
```